# Fibonacci clarification

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

As explained in Excursion 4.5, the Fibonacci numbers are defined by the rules:
F(0) = 0, F(1) = 1, and for all n with n ≥ 2, F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2).
Which of these claims about the Fibonacci numbers is false?
Select one:

a. For every n with n ≥ 5, F(n) ≥ 2n/2.

b. For every natural n, F(n) is divisible by 3 if and only if n is divisible by 4.

c. For every n, F(n) ≤ 2n.

d. The sum for i from 0 through n of F(i) is F(n+2) - 1.

This was a question on a test that I got wrong. My answer was b. I am looking to understand how this is possible. My understanding is that F(n) is a fibonacci number. If so, not all numbers are divisible by 3 and are also divisible by 4.

Comment: You can prove b. using induction, or just look at the residues one obtains when dividing F(n) by 3: <br/> $0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, \dots$

Comment: in (a), $2n/2$ looks odd; please check the source.

Comment: It's supposed to. But there have been questions before where later was given credit for being correct as well. Do it's possible that there are

Comment: A is correct. But why is b incorrect?

Comment: For b, note that in mod $3$, we have $\color{red}{0},\color{red}{1},1,2,0,2,2,1,\color{red}{0},\color{red}{1},1,...$

Comment: @Varoag b is not incorrect. $b$ is a true statement.

Comment: Doe $(a)$ really say $2n/2$? Or something else? Because $2n/2$ is sill.

Comment: It does say that Thomas Andrews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If so, not all numbers are divisible by 3 and are also divisible by 4.

The statement doesn't say that. The statement says that if $F(n)$ is divisible by $3$, then $n$ is divisible by $4$, and vice versa.

To see that this statement is true, I advise you to think about the fact that $$F(n+1)\equiv F(n) + F(n-1)\mod 3$$

and then look at the whole sequence modulo $3$. You might notice a pattern.